# Can 2 Users created with the same userName have the same results when doing "map.get(user);"?

Tags: java

Ok, see this `User` class

```
public class User{
 private String userName;
 public User(String userName){
     this.userName=userName;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof User))
      return false;
    User user = (User) obj;
    return user.userName.equals(this.userName);
 }
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    return userName.hashCode()  ;
 }
}
```

Now we got a `Map`

```
Map<User, List<String>> map=new ConcurrentHashMap<User, List<String>>();
```

now wee got these codes:

```
User  tom=new User("Tom");
List<String> tomList=new ArrayList<String>();
tomList.add("Test");
User mary=new User("Mary");
map.put(tom,tomList);
map.put(mary,new ArrayList<String>());
```

Now, we create a new object Tom

```
User  tom2=new User("Tom");
List<String> tomList=map.get(tom2);
```

My question is that `tomList` is `null` or not `null`

If it is null, then can we make it not `null`. That means instead of try to find the exact object we can just create object with same `userName` and we can do `map.get(user);`

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Why won't you try your code? It works as you expect.

Comment: I tried map.get(tom) & map.get(tom2) show the same result

Comment: So that's your answer. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`Map` keys are matched using `key.equals(k)`.

Or formally:
If the `Map` already contains a mapping from a key 'k' to a value 'v' such that key.equals(k), then `get(key)` method returns v, otherwise it returns null.

In your case:
User.equals() matches for *userName* String property, so map.get(tom2) is **not** null.
All User Objects named "Tom" will be considered as having the same key.

Answer (score 0):

**The behaviur you are asking is actually controlled by your code via the `equals()` (and `hashcode()`) function.** Let's take a look at the `equals()`:

```
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //two references are considered equal to each other,
    //if they are pointing to the same Object

    //This is the default equals implementation.
    if (this == obj)
      return true;

    //Two objects cannot be equal if even their types do not match.
    if (!(obj instanceof User))
      return false;

    //If their types matched, let's start comparing them field-by-field.
    //If all fields match, then (altough they are different objects
    //in memory) they represent the same real-world entity
    //in this case user Tom.
    User user = (User) obj;
    return user.userName.equals(this.userName);
 }
```

By removing the last part from your `equals()` and the corresponding part from `hashcode()` you can change the behaviur of the map to expect a reference **to the very same object**.